# Simple Jquery custom post type archive slide toggle in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I currently have an custom post archive that displays all posts(li's) in a month(ul's). I wish to have it so that when a user clicks on February then all the posts for that slide in or fade in. I would also like like to have the current months posts already displayed. Any advice or link to a tutorial would be great as my jquery is very basic.

Thanks for the help

```
<script>
            jQuery (document).ready(function() {
            jQuery ('.list-slide').hide();
            jQuery ('.list-slide-btn').click(function() {
                jQuery ('.list-slide').slideToggle(1500).delay(1500);
            }); 
        });
</script>
<div  class="album-list width50 float-left">
                    <?php       
                    $counter = 0;
                    $ref_month = '';
                    $monthly = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'albums',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        ));
                    if( $monthly->have_posts() ) : while( $monthly->have_posts() ) : $monthly->the_post();
                        if( get_the_date('mY') != $ref_month ) { 
                            if( $ref_month ) echo "\n".'</ul>';
                            echo "\n".'<h5 class="list-slide-btn">'.get_the_date('F Y').'</h5>';
                            echo "\n".'<ul class="list-slide">';
                            $ref_month = get_the_date('mY');
                            $counter = 0;
                        }

                    if( $counter++ < 31 ) echo "\n".'   <li><a href='.get_permalink($post->ID).'>'.get_the_date('D jS').' &#58;<br/>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a></li>';

                    endwhile; 
                    echo "\n".'</ul>';
                    endif; 
                    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: why `.delay(1500);` at the end..?

Comment: Yes there is no point to it, I will remove it. Can you help with the question? Thanks

Comment: sure why not..say what help you need..be quick i just have 30 min left today as i am near to closing for today..